# Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOException::get_Message()

Tags: php, pdo

My code was working until I upgraded EasyPHP from 13.1VC11 to 14.1VC9. Now, when I first start using PDO, it throws an error. I tried the code tester and it threw the same exact error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOException::get_Message() in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\binaries\home\codesource.php on line 9

I checked and as far as I can see, PDO is installed. I'm thinking that somehow the pointer to the code is messed up. I can't seem to get past this.

Here's the code from the code tester:

```
<?php
$dbusername="myuserid";
$dbpassword="mypassword";
try     {
    $dbh= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cdlmoves', $dbusername, $dbpassword); 
    }
catch   (PDOException $pe)
    {
    die ("I cannot connect to the database." . $pe->get_Message());
}
?>
```

Comment: [`getMessage()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.getmessage.php), not `get_Message()`

Comment: Voting to close; simple typographical error

Answer (score 2):

its [getMessage()](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.getmessage.php), so change

```
$pe->get_Message()
```

to

```
$pe->getMessage()
```

Comment: Thank you. This can be closed. A stupid mistake. I never hit it before  but the db login credentials changed so it finally threw the exception.